# How to access below json values in go fiber?

Tags: validation, go, jwt, go-fiber

This is the code I wrote. When I used `token.Claims` method it returns below result. And I need to access email value also for check whether who is the user. When I used `token.Claims.Email` it throws an error.

```
func User(c *fiber.Ctx) error {
    cookie := c.Cookies("jwt")
    claims := jwt.MapClaims{}
    token, _ := jwt.ParseWithClaims(cookie, claims, func(token *jwt.Token) (interface{}, error) {
        return []byte(SecretKey), nil
    })

    return c.JSON(token.Claims)
}
```

[This is the postman response. How to access below email address](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8fvgl.png)

Comment: Thank you for answering, It still throws an error like this `invalid operation: token.Claims["email"] (type jwt.Claims does not support indexing)`. How do I solve it.

Comment: `jwt-go` package.

Comment: Thank you I got an answer. The package is `github.com/dgrijalva/jwt-go`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just by checking out your code I'm guessing that you are using this [golang-jwt](https://github.com/golang-jwt/jwt) package.

After calling `jwt.ParseWithClaims` you should be able to access your claims over the already created `jwt.MapClaims` object named `claims` in your code.

Example without Fiber, only with golang-jwt, but logic stays the same:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "github.com/golang-jwt/jwt/v4"
)

// Created on https://jwt.io/
const tokenString = "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJlbWFpbCI6InRlc3RAbWFpbC5jaCJ9.Iv6oZWIX7Rrtag4d6h3-eJ3xdXLwoZ9PbotcvbjOvhI"
// Just as an example, make sure to pick a stronger key
const key = "1234567890"

func main() {
    claims := jwt.MapClaims{}
    token, err := jwt.ParseWithClaims(tokenString, claims, keyFunc)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(token.Valid)
    email, ok := claims["email"].(string)
    if !ok {
        panic("Couldn't parse email as string")
    }
    fmt.Println(email)
}

func keyFunc(*jwt.Token) (interface{}, error) {
    return []byte(key), nil
}
```